# How to access lambda function's value here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sum_(f, start, end):
    # 1st_value,_,__ = map(f,[start,end]) # how to get 1st value passed on lambda function here ? 
    # print(1st_value+start+end)
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sum_(lambda y: 1.0, 5, 10))) # 1st_value=1.0,2nd_value=5, 3rd_value=10
```

How can i get `1.0` value from lambda function inside `sum_()`? I tried `map()`, but it did not work.

I have gone to other similar questions too, but did not find my answer, so please don't mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the lambda function; you have passed the lambda function to the function `sum_`, but you are not calling the lambda :

```py
>>> def sum_(f, start, end):
        value = f(None) # Pass value of y
        print(start-end+value)
>>>> sum_(lambda y: 1.0, 5, 10)
-4.0
```

*A side note, `1st_value` that you have in commented part of the code is not a valid variable name.*

Comment: When i try that It gives a type error: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @Abhisheksoni, the solution now has the modified version of your code. It is working fine! Give it a try

Comment: thanks that above piece of code works but why this is not working then ? f = lambda y: 1.0, 5, 10
print(f(None) )

Comment: ` f = lambda y: 1.0, 5, 10` creates a tuple, and the first item in the tuple contains lambda function, it will work if you call first item in this tuple by: `f[0](None)`